# SSRS expression - Line break after 3rd hyphen

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I have a field that produces dates in 01-03-2022 - 07-03-2022 and want to put a line break after the 3rd hyphen so it displays like

```
01-03-2022 - 
07-03-2022
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

=REPLACE(Fields!MyDatesField.Value, " - ", vbcrlf)

All we are doing is looking for the "space hyphen space" pattern and replaceing with the carriage return and line feed characters (equivalent to Chr(13) + Chr(10) as far as I remember)

Comment: Thanks again Alan